# Navigation Drawer Android

Tags: java, android

I have created a app with app drawer, It shows error in switch case at Id. I tried to change but shows error in this line only.

Below is my java code, when I build it shows constant expression required

```
package com.example.dwcsongs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

public class drawer_left extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_left);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                // Handle item selection here
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_item1 :
                        // Handle item 1 selection
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_item2:
                        // Handle item 2 selection
                        break;
                    // Add more cases for other menu items
                }

                drawerLayout.closeDrawers(); // Close the drawer
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

navigation_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item1"
        android:title="Item 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item2"
        android:title="Item 2" />
    <!-- Add more items as needed -->
</menu>
```

Comment: switch-case does no longer work with android's IDs. Use an if-else chain instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use If else insted of switch case not working in case of android id in java only :

```
 if (id == R.id.nav_item1 ) {
   
 }else if (id == R.id.nav_item2 ) {
   
 }
```

Comment: Please avoid if else statements. Join the if else haters club. Only use if's:  if (id == R.id.nav_item1 ) { do what you want;
   return;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the switch cases if you add

```
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

to gradle.properties file.

Comment: Shows this when i build

Comment: Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

Comment: Ok. Did not think of that. Well... you have to do something more than.. Once you will have to do that anyway..  thanks.

Comment: Used ifelse instead switch may help me thanks

Comment: FYI: Only use if's. Join the club! ;-)

Comment: ok thank for the info